# What is a quantum algorithm that is the most efficient for numerical calculating a definite integral?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

What is a quantum algorithm that is the most efficient for numerical calculating an integral of a function, for example, of one variable on an interval from $a$ to $b$? For instance, the following integral:
$$ \int_1^2 3x^2\,dx .$$

Among methods for numerical calculating definite integrals there is non stochastic one (e.g. trapezoidal rule, Simpson's rule etc.) and stochastic one (Monte–Carlo method). Is it correct to assume that stochastic methods implemented in quantum computers will be the most efficient?

Comment: Quantum computers would be the least efficient for this, at least for the next 5 decades.

Comment: Unless you somehow use entanglement to speed up the computation, I doubt quantum computers will be useful tools for this task.

Comment: Why QC would be so bad for such tasks? @user1271772